# Windows/Linux iOS App Development (Compilation not needed)

Tags: ios, linux, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to develop iOS applications on Windows or Linux. While this may seem like a duplicate question, there is one more thing which I was unable to find in the already-existing questions: **I *do* have access to a Mac**. "Why don't you just develop it there," you may ask; there's a hitch: it's my girlfriend's Mac, so I can't monopolize it for the amount of time an app would take to develop.

So, basically, here is what I want to do: I would like to do the coding (and preferably some amount of pre-device testing) on Windows (or Linux) for the app, after which I can move it over to the Mac for compilation. Is there some free way of doing this (I've looked at Xamarin and Marmalade, but I cannot afford the licenses for those)? Thank you.

*P.S. While I realize that nothing is stopping me from simply cracking open Notepad++ and going at it, I was hoping for something with slightly better testing capabilities.*

Comment: Also I don't recommend this and it's a gray area of legality. You could setup a second partition and create a hackintosh. I've heard iatkos is easy to use and setup. The painful part is getting your drivers to work like they should. Go to the OSX86 forums and figure out what laptop/device is compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin, KendoUI, PhoneGap, Cordova are all frameworks that utilize HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript to create  apps that are portable to Android, Web, Windows Phone, BlackBerry and iOS. You need to find a framework like that. In order to compile for iOS/iPhone you need a Mac, but to develop you'll need one of those frameworks above. There is no native way of modifying in Windows, and compiling. Of course you could edit .m and .h files in a standard text editor, but you can't debug or compile unless you are in XCode on a Mac.

Unity3D/Unreal Engine 4 you can work in Windows, and it'll output the iOS XCode Project files, and source code. But you'll still need a Mac to compile it. One of the strict requirements by our friends at Apple.

Once the app is compiled you can submit to the App Store via Application Loader or directly in XCode. I've also heard people submit to the app store via Windows once it is compiled, but haven't done this myself.

Comment: Is there a similar framework which would compile the app into native code? I know Xamarin does, but the licensing issue bars that option.

Answer (score 2):

The above frameworks work but are not native code. If you want native, Xamarin compiles to Objective-C but has steep license. What it comes down to needing a Mac and Xcode to create native iOS applications. You can attempt a hackintosh but that may not be the easiest solution.